# Main references for Bayesian Event Tree method?

Tags: bayesian, forecasting, references

I am struggling to find the main references for the Bayesian Event Tree method.
At least in my research field, people cite authors that have applied this method to their specific problem, without citing those who first introduced it.
Statisticians, I suspect ;)

Can you help me with citing it properly?